# Complex price options. Am I stuck with 180 variations?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to come up with a solution for a client.

They sell parasols and each one has the following attributes:

- Colour
- Frame
- Size
- Base
- Bar

The way it is set up at the moment, there are 36 variations, and the colour attribute is set to 'any colour' as it doesn't effect price. The other 4 options, (Frame, Size Base & Bar) effect the price.

Now, they want to change the image when the colour swatch is clicked.

Normally, I would create variations from all attributes, and add a unique image for each variation. WooCommerce's native functionality would then take care of the image changing no problem. However, as each of the non-colour attribute affects price, it creates a situation where I need 180 variations!

To try to avoid this variation nightmare, I've built what I thought was a solution in ACF, where I create a relationship between the colour attributes and a custom image, and then I use JS to change the image when the swatch is clicked, independantly from the core functionality.

However, when a full combination is chosen and the price is generated, it calls the get_variation ajax call. This overides the image back to the default. This results in the image changing immediately when the swatch is clicked, but then sliding back to the default image when the variation loads.

Can anyone see a way around this whereby I can control the product image using the swatches, but not affect the variation.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea for you:

You'll need the ACF plugin for do this quickly.

With ACF, you'll create a [repeater](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) field on each product that you'll populate automaticly with all colors. For populate your repeater fields, put a look here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/

After you have populate your repeater fields you'll be able to add an image for each color.

When you have that, you can use JS for take the good image with the good color selected.

Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: This is a good idea and not sure who downvoted it. I actually tried implementing a solution using ACF to populate a dropdown of swatches and tie a gallery image to them. I have also used JS  to switch the images. It falls down at the last hurdle because although it changes the images, as soon as a full variation combination is chosen, it changes the image again. For example I click a swatch, it updates the image. The variation loads and resets the image again a second later.  If I could find a way of tying the ACF value to the actual woo order, I could do without color attributes altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question a few days ago. I had a similar problem and decided to share my code, so I wrote a blogpost about it. You can download the complete plugin from my Github.

https://tombroucke.be/blog/set-woocommerce-product-variation-thumbnail-by-attribute/

I have seen some premium plugins which enable you to bulk edit product (variations). These should also do the trick.